# Realize Mailchimp Double-Opt-In with API 3.0

Tags: mailchimp

I´m looking for a **comfortable way** to realize **double opt-in via mailchimp API 3.0**. It looks like there was an option in version 2.0 which told mailchimp to send an opt-in confirmation email automatically as soon as a new member is added via API call.

It seems this parameter is not available any more in API 3.0. **Has anyone an idea how to realize it** with the new version of the API?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

When using [Double Opt In](https://mailchimp.com/help/about-double-opt-in/) on a list, people who have filled out your signup form will have an API status of `pending` until they confirm their subscription.

In order to mimic that functionality in API v3.0, set the user's status to `pending` instead of `subscribed` in your `POST` call. See [How to Manage Subscribers](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/article/how-to-manage-subscribers) for more details.

Comment: I just changed subscribed to pending and it works perfectly; the opt-in email is sent.

Comment: Right on! You should be hired to rewrite Mail Chimp API documentation - less words, more straight-to-the point examples.

Comment: @TooMuchPete - I like that the answer is short and to the point, and the link is the same - but maybe something about "pending will always send a confirmation email, Even though you have not enabled double opt-in on your list in mailchimp" - I don't really know, the answer is good!