# Sending final welcome mail with Mailchimp API v3.0 without double opt-in

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I would like to use the Mailchimp v3.0 API to send a final welcome mail, without going through the double opt-in procedure.

If I set the status to "pending" I get the double opt-in, at least sometimes, and of course the final welcome mail, as described in this post 
[Realize Mailchimp Double-Opt-In with API 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251271/realize-mailchimp-double-opt-in-with-api-3-0?rq=1)

But I would like to do it without the double opt-in, as indicated should work automatically in this post [Sending Welcome Email when using Mailchimp API 3 List/Member Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243604/sending-welcome-email-when-using-mailchimp-api-3-list-member-method#new-answer)

I assume that the last post also requires the double opt-in, even if that is not mentioned in the post.

Anyone that have been able to do it in v3.0? I can do it in v2.0, but would like to use 3.0 going forward.

Comment: Have you tried setting the status to "Subscribed"? I don't know about sending the final welcome email, but try this: http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/enable-or-disable-final-welcome-email

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same kind of functionality, but unfortunately the final welcome email is only sent after a person has completed the double-opt in. Thus, as of right now Mailchimp does not support this out of the box in the list settings and you have to resort to other ways to send this kind of mail to your users.

Fortunately, you can actually achieve the same behavior using Mailchimp's automation feature: https://help.mailmunch.com/hc/en-us/articles/206143089-How-to-Enable-MailChimp-s-Welcome-Email-

For reference, the *send final welcome mail* option in the Mailchimp list dashboard has a tooltip that explicitly reads:

> When people opt-in to your list, send them an email welcoming them to your newsletter.

Answer (score -1):

Set Status to "Subscribed" to avoid the double opt-in. As for sending the final welcome email, you can try adjusting this setting from the form builder (Final welcome email, tick "Send a final welcome email") or from list settings (List name and defaults, tick "Send a final welcome email"), as described here: http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/enable-or-disable-final-welcome-email